# Buffer Overflow Sample: Why is this code dangerous?

Tags: c++, c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I'm fairly new to c and I'm reading a book regarding Software Vulnerabilities and I came across this buffer overflow sample, it mentions that this can cause a buffer overflow. I am trying to determine how this is the case.

```c
int handle_query_string(char *query_string)
{
    struct keyval *qstring_values, *ent;
    char buf[1024];
        
    if(!query_string) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    qstring_values = split_keyvalue_pairs(query_string);
        
    if((ent = find_entry(qstring_values, "mode")) != NULL) {
        sprintf(buf, "MODE=%s", ent->value);
        putenv(buf);
    }
}
```

I am paying close attention to this block of code because this appears to be where the buffer overflow is caused.

```c
if((ent = find_entry(qstring_values, "mode")) != NULL)
{
    sprintf(buf, "MODE=%s", ent->value);
    putenv(buf);
}
```

Comment: You're right that it's in that block. Do you see something in it that's writing to a fixed-size buffer without specifying what the maximum size is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very big thing here is that you passed a pointer to a local variable to `putenv`. The buffer will cease to exist when `handle_query_string` returns. After that it will contain garbage variables. Note that what `putenv` does require that the string passed to it remains unchanged for the rest of the program. From the documentation for putenv (emphasis mine):

> `int putenv(char *string);`
>
> The `putenv()` function adds or changes the value of environment variables.  The argument `string` is of the form name=value. If name does not already exist in the environment, then `string` is added to the environment. If name does exist, then the value of name in the environment is changed to value. **The string pointed to by `string` becomes part of the environment, so altering the string changes the environment.**

This can be corrected by using dynamic allocation. `char *buf = malloc(1024)` instead of `char buf[1024]`

Another thing is that `sprintf(buf, "MODE=%s", ent->value);` might overflow. That would happen if the string `ent->value` is too long. A solution there is to use `snprintf` instead.

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "MODE=%s", ent->value);
```

This prevents overflow, but it might still cause problems, because if `ent->value` is too big to fit in `buf`, then `buf` will for obvious reasons not contain the full string.

Here is a way to rectify both issues:

```
int handle_query_string(char *query_string)
{
    struct keyval *qstring_values, *ent;
    char *buf = NULL;

    if(!query_string)
        return 0;

    qstring_values = split_keyvalue_pairs(query_string);

    if((ent = find_entry(qstring_values, "mode")) != NULL)
    {
        // Make sure that the buffer is big enough instead of using
        // a fixed size. The +5 on size  is for "MODE=" and +1 is 
        // for the string terminator
        const char[] format_string = "MODE=%s";
        const size_t size = strlen(ent->value) + 5 + 1;
        buf = malloc(size);

        // Always check malloc for failure or chase nasty bugs
        if(!buf) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    

        sprintf(buf, format_string, ent->value);
        putenv(buf);
    }
}
```

Since we're using `malloc` the allocation will remain after the function exits. And for the same reason, we make sure that the buffer is big enough beforehand, and thus, using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` is not necessary.

Theoretically, this has a memory leak unless you use `free` on all strings you have allocated, but in reality, not freeing before exiting `main` is very rarely a problem. Might be good to know though.

It can also be good to know that even though this code now is fairly protected, it's still not thread safe. The content of `query_string` and thus also `ent->value` may be altered. Your code does not show it, but it seems highly likely that `find_entry` returns a pointer that points somewhere in `query_string`. This can of course also be solved, but it can get complicated.

Comment: Might be good to mention that `putenv()` requires that the the c string passed remains unmolested for the life of the program. A rare requirement.

Comment: @doug Puh, thanks. Your comment made me realize that there were some severe issues with my code.

Answer (score 2):

I think here is it, because your `buf` is only 1024 and because `ent->value` can have more than 1024, then this may overflow.

```
sprintf(buf, "MODE=%s", ent->value);
```

But depends of implementations of `split_keyvalue_pairs(query_string)`. If this function already checks the value and threat it (which I doubt).

Comment: _"more than 1024"_ should really be _"more than 1018"_ (or 1019, if that count includes the string terminator character in `env->value`).

Comment: Yes, one character or more will cause buffer overflow.  In this case, you ask for 1024 bytes, then you try safe 1025 will crash. If it s a server, then your server will break down.

Comment: Good question, by the way.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to crash.  It is undefined behavior.  It might appear to work fine.

Comment: And then, when you least expect it, eat your cat. Hey, The behaviour of undefined behaviour is undefined. Could do anything.

Answer (score 2):

klutt provided a good fix for the problem in a previous answer, so I'll try to go a bit more specific and in-depth on the exact nature of the overflow in your code.

1. `char buf[1024];`

This line allocates 1024 bytes on the stack, addressed by the pointer named `buf`.  The big problem here is that it is on the stack.  If you dynamically allocate using malloc (or my favorite: calloc), it will be on the heap.  The location doesn't necessarily prevent or fix an overflow.  But it can change the effect.  Right above (give or take some bytes) this space on the stack would be the return address from the function, and an overflow can change that causing the program to redirect when it returns.

2. `sprintf(buf, "MODE=%s", ent->value);`

This line is what actually performs the overflow.  sprintf = "string print format."  This means that the destination is a string (char *), and you are printing a formatted string.  It doesn't care about the length, it will just take the starting memory address of the destination string, and keep writing until it has finished.  If there's more than 1024 characters to be written (in this case), then it will go past the end of your buffer and overflow into other parts of memory.  The solution is to use the function snprint instead.  The "n" tells you that it will limit the amount to be written to the destination, and avoid an overflow.

The ultimate thing to understand is that a "buffer" does not actually exist.  It's simply not a thing.  It is a concept we use to order the area in memory, but the computer has no idea what a buffer is, where it starts, or where it ends.  So in writing, the computer doesn't really care if it is inside or outside of the buffer, and doesn't know where to stop writing.  So, we need to tell it very explicitly how far it is allowed to write, or it will just keep writing.